# Is the GC.KeepAlive official example valid?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I'm looking at the [official example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.keepalive?view=net-7.0#examples) of the `GC.KeepAlive` method. But I don't fully understand why the `GC.KeepAlive` is necessary there.

The GC collects all the objects that have no more references. To my understanding, the `hr` variable, which references the managed pointer, lives for the entire lifespan of the `Main` method context. Thus, the GC should never collect it.

The GC will collect it, **only if** it has an additional optimization (*) that knows that **even if** the `hr` references the object, it will not be used in the future.

I tried to find evidence for that extra optimization but didn't find one. I removed the `GC.KeepAlived` command, and the program continues to operate as expected (in Release build, fully optimized, no debugger attached).

I was able to make the GC collect `hr` by moving the `hr` decleration to **another method/context** that has shorter lifespan.

```
    public static void Register()
    {
        MyWin32.HandlerRoutine hr = new MyWin32.HandlerRoutine(Handler);
        MyWin32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(hr, true);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Use interop to set a console control handler.
        Register();

        // Give the user some time to raise a few events.
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting 30 seconds for console ctrl events...");

        // The object hr is not referred to again.
        // The garbage collector can detect that the object has no
        // more managed references and might clean it up here while
        // the unmanaged SetConsoleCtrlHandler method is still using it.

        // Force a garbage collection to demonstrate how the hr
        // object will be handled.
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        
        Thread.Sleep(30000);

        // Display a message to the console when the unmanaged method
        // has finished its work.
        Console.WriteLine("Finished!");

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Now, without the `GC.KeepAlive`, there is an error while triggering an event.
But once I hold the pointer to the delegate in the heap in the context of the `Main` method, there is no error without the `KeepAlive`.

My questions:

1. Is the official example valid? Because it works even without the `GC.KeepAlive`
2. Is the additional optimization (marked with (*) above), really exist? If so, in which .NET versions? because I can't see it (tested in .NET 6)

Comment: The example is valid. `hr` is a variable which means it's orphaned and eligible for garbage collection once the method exits. `GC.KeepAlive(hr)` prevents this. The only reason you don't see this is because `Main` is in scope for the duration of the program. `method/context that has shorter lifespan.` exactly. You're trying to read too much into a short example meant to just show how a method is called

Comment: To see the error, you'll probably have to call `GC.Collect()` in addition to using a release build. The main method is just to short to trigger a GC, even if hr is eligible for collection.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is why I'm asking if this example is valid. I mean, why they didn't split the registration to another function as I did? Because in that particular example you don't really need the GC.KeepAlive

Comment: @PMF there is an explicit call to `GC.Collect` and I run it on Release.

Comment: Ups, it seems I need new glasses :-(

Comment: This is a documentation example meant to show the function call, not a guidance document, but it's actually fully valid. Check [this blog post instead](https://minidump.net/c-using-gc-keepalive-in-async-methods-8d20fd79f0a0), which explains that native calls are treated as weak references. Even in the doc example, `hr` is no longer used after `MyWin32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(hr, true);` so it's considered orphaned. Putting `GC.KeepAlive(hr);` at the very end creates a strong reference to `hr` at that point, which means `hr` isn't considered orphaned ... unless you use `async`

Comment: The blog post also explains that the JIT compiler uses a *less* optimized version of the code for the first 30 invocations before spending the effort to create a more optimized version. It's quite possible that `hr` survives because the less optimized code was used.

Comment: Interesting, will try to make it inside of a loop or something... Will update

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, this is the thing. JIT! With `   [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]` the example works as intended. If you want to write it as an answer and I will mark it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collect objects still in scope - GC.Collect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425052/collect-objects-still-in-scope-gc-collect)

Answer (score 1):

> To my understanding, the hr variable, which references the managed pointer, lives for the entire lifespan of the Main method context. Thus, the GC should never collect it.

This is false. The GC is allowed to collect objects as soon as the reference has been used for the last time. It is perfectly possible that an object is collected while a method for that very same object is running.

> The GC will collect it, only if it has an additional optimization (*) that knows that even if the hr references the object, it will not be used in the future.

This is more correct, I'm not sure it is specified in the language documentation. But it is fairly well explained in the documentation for KeepAlive. I.e. the GC cannot track references "owned" by native code, so may prematurely collect objects.

> I tried to find evidence for that extra optimization but didn't find one. I removed the GC.KeepAlived command, and the program continues to operate as expected (in Release build, fully optimized, no debugger attached).

My guess is that this is due to various changes in .Net since this example was created. There has happened a lot to the runtime that could affect collections. I can not say what specific reason change caused this, and it may also not be completely deterministic.

This does not invalidate the principles the example is meant to demonstrate, but it does make the example rather poor if it can no longer demonstrate the actual problem behavior.