# C# how to clear memory

Tags: c#

In my winform app I have download button (Save_button_Click), which save my datagridview data to a csv file. Unfortunately, once the file is downloaded the process still occupy a memory (466 MB of RAM). Is there any method how to clear the memory?

```
private void Save_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "csv files|*.csv";
        sfd.Title = "Save output to file";
        sfd.DefaultExt = "csv";
        sfd.CheckFileExists = true;
        sfd.CheckPathExists = true;
        sfd.RestoreDirectory = true;
        sfd.FileName = "Output.csv";
        sfd.CreatePrompt = true;
        sfd.OverwritePrompt = true;
        sfd.InitialDirectory = GetDownloadFolderPath();

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                int columnCount = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
                string columnNames = "";
                string[] outputCsv = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count + 1];

                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                {
                    columnNames += dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText.ToString() + ",";
                }
                outputCsv[0] += columnNames;

                for (int i = 1; (i - 1) < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i - 1].Cells[j].Value != null)
                        {
                            outputCsv[i] += dataGridView1.Rows[i - 1].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + ",";
                        }
                    }
                    refresh_progressBar(i, dataGridView1.Rows.Count);
                }
                File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, outputCsv, Encoding.UTF8);

                MessageBox.Show("Data Exported Successfully !!!", "Info");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error :" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    },
            else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Record To Export !!!", "Info");
    }

    GC.Collect();

    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just open the file and write the lines one by one..?

Comment: Have you considered writing each row to file immediately? As opposed to filling a huge string array before writing everything to disk?

Comment: Garbage collector will run by itself, there is no need to call it here.

Comment: you have to use disk as swap

Comment: "Is there any method how to clear the memory?" Close the form? You still have all the data in the grid that needs memory.

Comment: And its a desktop app that does things locally so its saving not downloading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collect objects still in scope - GC.Collect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425052/collect-objects-still-in-scope-gc-collect)

Comment: `GC.Collect` will only collect objects not in scope. In debug mode that is only after the function ends. I agree though that it shouldn't be necessary to call GC directly.

Comment: How much data is in your `DataGridView`?

Comment: there is 5000 rows and about 100 columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question, but might just solve your problem.

Instead of populating everything in memory, you could just write straight to disk; something like this.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName, false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var columnCount = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
    // Write header
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
    {
        sw.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText);
        if (i < columnCount - 1)
        {
            sw.Write(",");
        }
    }
    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
    // Write rows
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            var value = dr.Cells[i].Value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                sw.Write(value.ToString());
            }
            if (i < columnCount - 1)
            {
                sw.Write(",");
            }
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: `sw.WriteLine` seems more idiomatic than `sw.Write(sw.NewLine)`

Comment: @Charlieface `sw.WriteLine("")`?

Comment: Hi, thx for your response. I can say the saving is faster but the memory usage is almost the same.

Comment: Then the memory usage wasn't caused by this - you do have all of the data there in the grid, that's bound to require memory too.

Comment: i have a main form with treeview, textbox, datagridview, two buttons (1st button run the query and fill the datagrid view and 2nd save datagridview data to csv file).
when i start the app the memory usage is 27 MB, after filling the datagrid view 73 MB. when i click on the Save button (code in description), now i'm using your one, the memory usage ends on the usage 469 MB

Comment: Then it's possible accessing all of the grid view rows causes extra allocations. I'd consider rewriting things so you don't read from the data grid to write to the file.

Comment: I have replaced the output source from datagridview to dataset and can say it helped. the memory usage is extremely low now. thx for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

The 'String[] outputCsv' variable is local to that function and is automatically deallocated once leaving the scope of that function. Memory usage might spike when this function is called but should return back to normal.

```
File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, outputCsv, Encoding.UTF8);
```

^^^ Will automatically close the file when done.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=net-8.0

The data that is eventually written to a CSV file is stored in your dataGridView. How much data is in there?